# Can FFmpeg resume after stream resumes？

Tags: ffmpeg

When receiving video stream with FFmpeg, if the stream is interrupted, will FFmpeg resume after the stream resumes?

Suppose I'm using FFmpeg to receive an RTSP video stream and dump it as an MP4 file. If the RTSP stream is interrupted for a few seconds (or minutes) for a signal or other reason, will FFmpeg also interrupt? Will FFmpeg continue to receive after RTSP stream resumes?

Answer (score 0):

no, if ffmpeg exited for some reason, You need to re-execute it manually